# How to filter multi-dimensional list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list:

```
[1,4,4,2,[[[4],5]],5,6]
```

How can i filter this list, that i will have unique values, but save dimensions for elements?

result:

```
[1,4,2,[[5]],6]
```

Comment: What criteria should be used to decide which copy of a given value should remain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have recursive function that works like any other unique-finding solution you might find online, but when it encounters an inner list, it calls itself with this inner list (getting only the uniques from it), also passing as argument the set of already seen elements (so that the "uniques from it" is defined as entirely new elements).

try this:

```py
lst = [1, 4, 4, 2, [[[4], 5]], 5, 6]


def unique(lst, already_seen):
    result = []
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            inner_uniques = unique(item, already_seen)
            if len(inner_uniques) > 0:
                result.append(inner_uniques)
        else:  # assuming item is a number
            if item in already_seen:
                continue
            else:  # new number
                result.append(item)
                already_seen.add(item)
    return result


result = unique(lst, set())  # starting with an empty ser
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 2, [[5]], 6]
```

Comment: Sorry for not the best example. Your code work good, but if try to use this example:[1,4,4,2,[[[4],5]],5,6] , it returns [1,4,2[[[],5]],6] . I try to find a way, to delete the empty list (near with '5').

Comment: @YuriMolodyko OK, I edited it, now the result of the recursive call will be added only if there were unique values in the inner list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that modifies the original list instead of making a new one (and returns it, which isn't so Pythonic but can be useful):

```
def remDups( s, seen=set() ):
    to_pop = []
    for i,v in enumerate(s):
        if isinstance(v,list):
            remDups( v, seen )
        elif v in seen:
            to_pop = [i]+to_pop
        else:
            seen.add(v)
    for i in to_pop:
        s.pop(i)
    return s
```